# How can I access to session in api handler?

Tags: next.js, next-auth

I want to get the session in my API rout. I have tried these two methods, but neither works.

1-

```
let session = await getSession({req})
```

terminal log at first time (first render) :

```
{
  user : { name: 'Amir', email: 'test@gmail.com' } ,
  expires: '2024-02-08T09:06:39.456Z'
}
```

terminal log at second time :

```
[next-auth][error][CLIENT_FETCH_ERROR] 
https://next-auth.js.org/errors#client_fetch_error undefined {
  error: {},
  url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/auth/session',
  message: undefined
}
```

---

2-

```
let session = await getServerSession(authOptions)
```

The error:
`Invariant: headers() expects to have requestAsyncStorage, none available.`

my goal is just access to user in session for validate my jwt

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found the solution.
You should add the secret to your `authOptions` and pass it to `getServerSession` like:

```
let session = await getServerSession(req , res , authOptions)
```